# Deleting completely a html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am aware of **.remove()** , I am using it and its working fine, I mean its removing the element which I want. But I think it doesn't removes it permanently. On right clicking in browser window selecting **View page source** I am still able to see those removed elements.
I want to remove them completely or say permanently.
Please help.

Comment: It's removed permanently, but "view source" is not an accurate way to check the DOM, it just shows you the original source, you'll need to open the DOM inspector instead.

Comment: I'm not sure by what you mean with permanently. Do you mean you wish to edit the HTML? Because everything you remove with `remove()` will be back once you refresh the page.

Comment: @user3008011: It's fairly clear this is the standard "view source" fallacy.

Comment: **You guys are answering fine I am appreciating but why are you rating me down?**

Comment: You might wanna read this link : http://css-tricks.com/dom/

Answer (score 7):

`.remove()` removes them completely. The reason you still seem then in the view page source is because the page source does not change based on javascript. The page source shows how the page originally looked when it was first loaded, not how it currently is.

If you look in the developers console, you will see that they are no longer there.

Likewise, if you dynamically add a new element with javascript/jquery, it will not show that element in the page source.

Comment: *"The page source shows how the page originally looked when it was first loaded..."* More commonly, it gets re-requested and the (static) response to that request is shown. But it comes to the same thing; dynamic changes to the DOM aren't reflected.

Answer (score 2):

**Page Source and DOM are two different different things**, whenever you edit the elements or remove them it get removes from **DOM** and not from page source. That means The javascript manipulate the DOM not the source which come from the server.

[**DOM**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html): The Document Object Model (DOM) is an application programming interface (API) for valid HTML and well-formed XML documents.

The view source always shows the content came from the server initially without any modification. Use **[DEVELOPER CONSOLE](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)** in browsers to see the live DOM manipulation.

*Note: Press **F12** to enable console on major browser*

Answer (score 1):

view source render the code within the page that you have written(*static*)

for *dynamic changes/view* inspect the elements tab in developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

View page source shows the content of the original HTML file, as returned by the HTTP server. The DOM can be altered with javascript, but the source will not change.

Answer (score 1):

You Cannot permenantly remove the dom elements using jquery or javascript. .remove() is totally different from your logic. just it removes temporary hide from the dom elements suppose you refresh the page it comes again it is jquery magic.