# i need to delete target attribute from anchor if its value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For the sake of W3c validation i need to remove target attribute from all anchors where target value is null

i had following code inside body

```
<div>
 <a href="#" target="">home emput</a>
 <a href="#" target="blank">home</a>
 <a href="#" target="">home empty</a>
 <a href="#">home</a>
</div>
```

Here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var target = []
  var i = 0;
  $("body a").each(function () {
   target[i++] = $(this).attr("target");
   if($(this).attr("target") == ""){
     $(this).removeAttr("target");
   }
  });
 console.log(target);
});
```

This code is working fine when I view console empty targets are removed. But when I view the source (Ctrl+u), targets are still there,

I just want to delete them.

Comment: `$('a[href=""]').removeAttr('target')`.

Comment: Yes ! Page source still showing, May be this will be helpfull and possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021488/deleting-completely-a-html-element/#answer-21021533

Comment: The source wont change, since it is the "source", but , if you check within the console , you'll see that it has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, its working

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var target = []
  var i = 0;
  $("body a").each(function () {
   target = $(this).attr("target");
   if(target == "")
   {
    $(this).removeAttr("target");
   }
  });
 //console.log(target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <a href="#" target="">home emput</a>
 <a href="#" target="blank">home</a>
 <a href="#" target="">home empty</a>
 <a href="#">home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this to remove..

```
$('a[target=""]').removeAttr('target');
```

but you cannot achieve this while considering W3 Validation, it grabs page content without executing JS, so the best practice is to hide it using server side script(PHP).

Answer (score 1):

As you are using "$", I assume you have jQuery

```
$("a[target='']").each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("target");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6g6t60pa/