# javascript) remove() removes element , but still can find and get access to removed element and its children

Tags: javascript, dom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

I read this documentation and this says

The ChildNode.remove() method removes the object from the tree it belongs to

but in this code

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  let tableRef = document.querySelector('table');
  tableRef.remove();
  createColumn(tableRef);
})
function createColumn(tableNodeRef){
  let rowSum = 0;
  let trRef = null;
  let tdRef = null;
  let tdTextRef = null;
  let i = 0;
  let trRefs = tableNodeRef.querySelectorAll('tr');
  console.log(tableNodeRef);
  console.log(trRefs);
}
```

tableRef.remove() removes table tag, and I can't see table tag in chrome developer tool's elements section, so I must say remove() works fine, but when I try 
console.log(tableNodeRef);
console.log(trRefs);

[image]

I can't understand why? mozilla documentation says remove() removes the object from the tree it belongs too  and [Deleting completely a html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021488/deleting-completely-a-html-element) in this link 
people say remove() removes elements completely, but why my console.log still gets table and tr elements?

Comment: It removes it from the tree, but as long as you keep a reference to it, it will not remove it from memory.

Comment: Element is removed from DOM tree, the reference still lives until destroyed, eg. `delete tableRef`

Comment: `delete tableRef` / `tableRef = null`

Comment: thanks to both of you. Now I understnad

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava thank you, I didn't know you commented and removed my previous comment, sorry

Comment: I suppose you refer to "It's removed permanently, but "view source" is not an accurate way to check the DOM". This comment is talking about the DOM tree.